# Descobrindo ultimo item do vetor no foreach?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou precisando sabe qual é o ultimo item do vetor para que quando for o ultimo não adicionar uma virgula:

***Exemplo:***

```
SEM SABER QUAL É O ULTIMO ITEM
1,2,3,4,5,

SABENDO QUAL É A ULTIMA VIRGULA
1,2,3,4,5
```

Eu faço um `foreach` na variável, e incremento uma virgula ao texto, porém no ultimo não será necessário adicionar a virgula devido ser ao ultimo. Estou utilizando `LARAVEL 5.4` juntamente com o `blade` para manipulação do `HTML`.

***Segue o código:***

```
@foreach($cliente->compras as $compra)
    {{$compra->produto}},
@endforeach
```

do jeito que se encontra em cima, ele esta colocando a ultima virgula, porém é normal levando em consideração que não esta se fazendo nenhuma logica para o mesmo sair.

Relações e `Model`

***Compras***

```
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Compras', 'COD_IDENT_CLIEN', 'COD_COMPR_VENDA');
}

public function produtos()
{
    return $this->HasMany('App\ComprasProdutos', 'COD_DAXXX_VENDA', 'COD_DAXXX_VENDA');
}
```

***Compras -> Produtos***

```
public function compra()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Compras', 'COD_DAXXX_VENDA', 'COD_DAXXX_VENDA');
}

public function item()
{
    return $this->BelongsTo('App\Produto', 'COD_IDENT_PRODU', 'COD_BARRA_PRODU');
}
```

***Produtos***

```
public function compras()
{
     return $this->BelongsTo('App\ComprasProdutos', 'COD_BARRA_PRODU', 'COD_IDENT_PRODU');
}
```

***Código*** `Blade`

```
@foreach($cliente->compras as $compra)
<div class="list-group-item media">
   <div class="checkbox pull-left">
            #{{$compra->COD_DAXXX_VENDA}}
        </div>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="actions dropdown">
                <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/clientes/compra/{{ $cliente->COD_IDENT_CLIEN }}">
                        Visualizar
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="lgi-heading">
                @foreach($compra->produtos as $produto)
                    {{-- {{dd($produto->item)}} --}}
                    {{$produto->item->TXT_NOMEX_PRODU}}
                    @if ($produto->last != $produto)
                        {{','}}
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o item fazer parte de uma [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) use o método [`last`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-last) da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    $last = $cliente->compras->last();
?>

@foreach($cliente->compras as $compra)
    {{$compra->produto}}
    @if ($last->produto != $compra->produto) {{','}} @endif
@endforeach
```

@@Edit

```
<div class="media-body">
    <div class="lgi-heading">
        <?php $last = $compra->produtos->last(); ?>
        @foreach($compra->produtos as $produto)
            {{-- {{dd($produto->item)}} --}}
            {{$produto->item->TXT_NOMEX_PRODU}}
            @if (last->COD_IDENT_PRODU != $produto->COD_IDENT_PRODU)
                {{','}}
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections)
- [collection - last](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-last)